# Running `tail -F $file` then removing outputted lines

Tags: audio, unix, ffmpeg, mp3, tail

Long story short; I'm running this command to stream a forever growing audio file `audio.mpg` into `ffmpeg`

```
tail -F audio.mp3 | ffmpeg -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

`audio.mp3` is being SSH'd from another server which has a capture device feeding the data through.
This is working correctly, however `audio.mp3` is constantly growing, and all I really need is to send the tail `mp3` data to `ffmpeg` in order encode and send it to `ffserver` on the same machine.

Is there a command I can run to output tail -F and also remove the outputted data from `audio.mp3`.

In essence, I want to put a 1MB limit on the file size of `audio.mp3`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a "named pipe" problem (Sherlock Holmes, please forgive me). Since the data is not supposed to remain on your system, you should create a named pipe,

```
 mkfifo my_pipe
```

and then have the SSH process write to it, and you can read from it:

```
cat < my_pipe | ffmpeg -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

When the process that writes data has completed, an EOF will appear in cat, and you will be free to stop the cat-ing by means of Ctrl+C. Of course you can also be smarter, writing a small script that waits on an EOF; as long as it does not find it, it passes the data along, when it does find the EOF, it shuts down the operation. This way you do not have to monitor the whole process.

Comment: (1) Rather than `cat < my_pipe | ffmpeg -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm`, you could say `ffmpeg -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm < my_pipe` or `< my_pipe ffmpeg -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm`.  (2) When the process that writes data has completed, an EOF will appear in the pipe, and `ffmpeg` should terminate, just as it would if it were reading from an ordinary file.  You shouldn’t need Ctrl+C.

Comment: good point, ty.

Comment: Thanks Marius, I never knew FIFO's existed, but upon searching about them, I can see how handy they can be!

Comment: They are used for inter-process communication, of which this is but a simple example. There are spiffier ones.